# change default hover in selectItem in IE10 smartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

how to change the blue color (default) hover in the selectItem compnent, in IE10?
I changed it  in firefox using:`selectItem.setPickListBaseStyle("newStyle");`
,but in IE it didn't apply.

Comment: What did you write in Firefox? The more details you give, the better are the chances for correct answer.